# Dividing by zero in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to implement a recursive algorithm calculating the Bernoulli numbers. 
But, I get "division by zero", and I can't figure out why. So I need some help with the logic.

When running the program with bernoulli 0, it prints 1, so the if statement seems to work. Bur not for arguments > 0

Thanks for your help!

```
(defn binom [r, n, k]
  (if (= k 0) r ;Om k == 0, returnera r
  (binom (* r (/ (- n (+ k 1)) k )) n (- k 1))
))

(defn bernoulli [n]
  (if (= n 0) 1
    (- 1 (apply + (for [k (range n)] (/ (* (binom 1 n k) (bernoulli k)) (- n (+ k 1)))))))
  )

(println (bernoulli 4))
```

And I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero, compiling:(/afs/kth.se/home/f/d/fdiffner/Desktop/X2/bernoulli.clj:9:4)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7145)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7089)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:336)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.divide(Numbers.java:156)
    at user$bernoulli$iter__2__6$fn__7$fn__8.invoke(bernoulli.clj:8)
    at user$bernoulli$iter__2__6$fn__7.invoke(bernoulli.clj:8)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at user$bernoulli.invoke(bernoulli.clj:8)
    at user$bernoulli$iter__2__6$fn__7$fn__8.invoke(bernoulli.clj:8)
    at user$bernoulli$iter__2__6$fn__7.invoke(bernoulli.clj:8)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at user$bernoulli.invoke(bernoulli.clj:8)
    at user$eval17.invoke(bernoulli.clj:11)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6706)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7133)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: This is a place where tracing execution would do a lot of good. Print your values at the top of each function, and you can see the arguments that triggered your immediate bug (and be able to reason about how it happened).

Comment: Also, at least use line breaks (so that you can identify the invocation better in the stack trace), maybe also intermediate variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `for` expression:

```
(for [k (range n)] (/ (* (binom 1 n k) (bernoulli k)) (- n (+ k 1))))
```

In particular, the division:

```clj
(/ (* (binom 1 n k) (bernoulli k))
   (- n (+ k 1)))
```

The last part, when `n` is 1 and k is 0 (which is what will happen when `n` is 1 on entry), then `(- n (+ k 1))` evaluates to `(- 1 (+ 0 1))`, which is 0.  As a result, you end up with division by 0.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks a lot!! 
Should have seen this by myself, but you saved my day